# SBT installation error (module not found: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6)

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to install SBT. I went through few cycles of reinstalling SBT and JAVA, restarting pc and so on. Everything I was able to find in Google about similar issues seems to refer to later stages of using sbt.

I'm a complete newbie, so I might have missed something obvious along the way.

Here's what I do:

1. I install SBT via msi installer.
2. I run "sbt" in command prompt.
   This is command prompt window (I manually broke all the links in the same way in order to be able to post this question):

   ```
   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
   (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone.

   C:\Users\Jakub>sbt
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
   Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar (283ms)
   :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi
       confs: [default]
       1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (111kB/16ms)
   Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.13 ...
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/jars/sbt.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13!sbt.jar (2892ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.6/scala-library-2.10.6.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6!scala-library.jar (942ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar (3227ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/jars/compiler-interface.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar (2865ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/jars/actions.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar (2861ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/jars/main-settings.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar (2965ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/interface/0.13.13/jars/interface.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.13!interface.jar (2807ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/jars/io.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar (2939ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/jars/ivy.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar (2954ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/logging/0.13.13/jars/logging.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.13!logging.jar (2876ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/logic/0.13.13/jars/logic.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.13!logic.jar (2759ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/process/0.13.13/jars/process.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.13!process.jar (2825ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/run/0.13.13/jars/run.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.13!run.jar (2820ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/jars/command.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar (2973ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.0-M1/launcher-interface-1.0.0-M1.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.0-M1!launcher-interface.jar (397ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/classpath/0.13.13/jars/classpath.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.13!classpath.jar (2874ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/jars/completion.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar (2948ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/jars/api.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar (2861ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-integration/0.13.13/jars/compiler-integration.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.13!compiler-integration.jar (2895ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-ivy-integration/0.13.13/jars/compiler-ivy-integration.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.13!compiler-ivy-integration.jar (2794ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/relation/0.13.13/jars/relation.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.13!relation.jar (2983ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/task-system/0.13.13/jars/task-system.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.13!task-system.jar (2820ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/tasks/0.13.13/jars/tasks.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.13!tasks.jar (2847ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/tracking/0.13.13/jars/tracking.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.13!tracking.jar (2767ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/testing/0.13.13/jars/testing.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.13!testing.jar (2832ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.6/scala-compiler-2.10.6.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6!scala-compiler.jar (1139ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.6/scala-reflect-2.10.6.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.6!scala-reflect.jar (305ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/control/0.13.13/jars/control.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.13!control.jar (2788ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/jars/collections.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar (3080ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.13/jline-2.13.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.13!jline.jar (526ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/classfile/0.13.13/jars/classfile.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.13!classfile.jar (3011ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/jars/incremental-compiler.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar (3007ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/jars/compile.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar (2835ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/persist/0.13.13/jars/persist.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.13!persist.jar (3280ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.10/0.4.2/jars/sbinary_2.10.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.10;0.4.2!sbinary_2.10.jar (3221ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/cross/0.13.13/jars/cross.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.13!cross.jar (2765ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.50/jsch-0.1.50.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.50!jsch.jar (522ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/serialization_2.10/0.1.2/serialization_2.10-0.1.2.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#serialization_2.10;0.1.2!serialization_2.10.jar (330ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-pickling_2.10/0.10.1/scala-pickling_2.10-0.10.1.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-pickling_2.10;0.10.1!scala-pickling_2.10.jar (489ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json4s/json4s-core_2.10/3.2.10/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.json4s#json4s-core_2.10;3.2.10!json4s-core_2.10.jar (344ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spire-math/jawn-parser_2.10/0.6.0/jawn-parser_2.10-0.6.0.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.spire-math#jawn-parser_2.10;0.6.0!jawn-parser_2.10.jar (203ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spire-math/json4s-support_2.10/0.6.0/json4s-support_2.10-0.6.0.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.spire-math#json4s-support_2.10;0.6.0!json4s-support_2.10.jar (198ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/quasiquotes_2.10/2.0.1/quasiquotes_2.10-2.0.1.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalamacros#quasiquotes_2.10;2.0.1!quasiquotes_2.10.jar (382ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json4s/json4s-ast_2.10/3.2.10/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.json4s#json4s-ast_2.10;3.2.10!json4s-ast_2.10.jar (197ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.6/paranamer-2.6.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.6!paranamer.jar (256ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/cache/0.13.13/jars/cache.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.13!cache.jar (3150ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/test-agent/0.13.13/jars/test-agent.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.13!test-agent.jar (2881ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/test-interface/1.0/test-interface-1.0.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0!test-interface.jar (393ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.13/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.13!apply-macro.jar (3008ms)
   downloading ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/template-resolver-0.1.jar ...
       [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar (193ms)

   :: problems summary ::
   :::: WARNINGS
       problem while downloading module descriptor: ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6.pom: Read timed out (19300ms)

               module not found: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6

       ==== local: tried

         C:\Users\Jakub\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6\ivys\ivy.xml

         -- artifact org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6!ivy.jar:

         C:\Users\Jakub\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6\jars\ivy.jar

       ==== Maven Central: tried

         ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6.pom

       ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

         ht tps://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivys/ivy.xml

       ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

         ht tps://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivys/ivy.xml

               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

               ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

               :: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6: not found

               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



   :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
   unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6: not found
   Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
   (see C:\Users\Jakub\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
   Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.13
   ```

If I try to run sbt now command prompt contains the same message starting at

```
:: problems summary ::
```

And this is part of C:\Users\Jakub.sbt\boot that seems to contain description of problem (whole file greatly exceeds character limit)

```
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.13
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.13
Module descriptor is processed : org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13
    report for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 default produced in C:\Users\Jakub\.sbt\boot\resolution-cache\org.scala-sbt-boot-app-default.xml
    resolve done (128406ms resolve - 106277ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6.pom: Read timed out (19300ms)

        module not found: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Jakub\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6!ivy.jar:

      C:\Users\Jakub\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6\jars\ivy.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6.pom

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivys/ivy.xml

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:350)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:350)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

What should I do, what could I've missed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to add repositories to `~/.sbt/repositories`

```
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. I did see this solution mentioned somewhere, but I just don't know how to do it - my first contact with both sbt and Java. How do I do what you just said? Google doesn't really answer "how to add repositories sbt"

Comment: Oh, I literally create a file without extension and put it there. I didn't know it can be that simple. Thanks again, works.

Comment: you can also use this command for repo file `sbt -Dsbt.repository.config=<path-to-your-repo-file>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installed sbt on ubuntu.

The solution was to configured in the environment the JAVA_HOME.

by running this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment

#Add next line (this is my rute of java virtual machine)
#For default forever the rute of the java virtual machine is in /usr/lib/jvm
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Save and reboot, then check the variable, by running this command:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```